# Is Allah's divine powers similar to superpowers? Or are they different?

Tags: allah, divine-attributes

Does Allah's Divine Powers similar to superpowers? If a character has an ability to resurrect the dead, is that similar to Allah's divine powers or do we call that superpowers? Is Allah's divine powers similar to superpowers?

Answer (score 0):

No, and it’s not good to compare Allah’s divine powers to anyone or anything. He is the most powerful and no one can share in His descriptions.

Allah knows best.